# Exporting DB file from root directory to external storage in android

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to export Database file from root directory to download directory. The database is created using Room, everything is working perfectly, i can add data, delete and update data , but when i try to export database it gives **exception**
***android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)***

i am using following lines of code to export db.

```
  private void exportDB() {

        if (checkPermission()) {


            try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                boolean ans = sd.canWrite();
                if (ans) {
                    String currentDBPath = "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME + "";
                    String backupDBPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/";
                    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                    if (!backupDB.exists())
                        backupDB.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                    if (currentDB.exists()) {
                        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();

                        if (backupDB.exists()) {
                            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                            src.close();
                            dst.close();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your database has been exported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size()); at this line it gives Exception

**Anyone Please help me to get rid of this error, Thanks alot**

Comment: What kind of exception. Stack trace please.

Comment: `if (!backupDB.exists())
                        backupDB.getParentFile().mkdirs();` You are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). Better: `if (!backupDB.exists())
                        if(!backupDB.getParentFile().mkdirs() return;` Also display a toast then to inform the user.

Comment: `String currentDBPath = "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME + "";` You should use `getDataBaseDir()` And one does not call that root directory.

Comment: The complaint is that you try to open a stream for a directory. Please check if you accidently created a directory for that filename.

Comment: `if (backupDB.exists())` That makes no sense.You will never be able to create the file for the first time.

Comment: @blackapps
 i am successfully able to copy database file but that new file does not contain any data inside, do you have any idea about this sir?

Comment: I wonder how you can call that 'successfully' if you have an exception and the file is empty.

Comment: i found the error, the error was i wasn't providing file name in the backup folder, so when i provided the file it copied successfully but it is still empty :

String backupDBPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME + "_bak";